# Call to the external applications like(tel: , sms: , mailto:) is not working on Intel xdk

Tags: android, cordova, intel-xdk

I am a newbie and want to build a hybrid application using Intel xdk with cordova 6.2.0. For some reasons I am not able to make a call to external applications like `tel:` or `mailto:` My settings are as follows
[Screenshot of the intent settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZqVA.jpg)

Please help.

Edit: Whenever I click on `<a href="tel:xxxxxxx">0000000</a>` it prompts only once when I load the whole project again but does not respond in the later try.

Answer (score 0):

For Working with External Intents you have to write javascript code like this in your html page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $("#page_content a").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  window.open($(e.currentTarget).attr('href'), '_system', 'location=yes');
});
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I had this problem with the emulator, but when I built and ran the apk on my android it was fine. Don't know what went wrong with the emulator.